# 64-bit integer implementation for 8-bit microcontroller

Tags: c, optimization, 64-bit, performance, microcontroller

I'm working on OKI 431 microcontroller. This is 8-bit microcontroller. We don't like to have any floating point operation to be performed in our project so we've eliminated all floating point operations and converted them into integer operations in some way. But we cannot eliminate one floating point operation because optimizing the calculation for integer operation requires 64-bit integer which the micro doesn't natively support. It has C compiler that supports upto 32-bit integer operation. The calculation takes too long time which is noticeable in a way to user.

I'm wondering if there is any 64-bit integer library that can be easily used in C for microcontoller coding. Or what is the easiest way to write such thing efficiently? Here efficiently implies minimize amount of time required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure compiler doesn't support 64 bit long integers unsing long long unsigned or similar?

Comment: yes i'm sure. it is surprising but the compiler is very basic.

Comment: Why is 64bit required? What type of operation is it?

Comment: it is conversion of raw humidity reading from a humidity sensor to actual relative humidity.

Comment: is there a specific operation, multiply for example?  hopefully not divide, I am guessing for a conversion probably a multiply and an add.  add is easy, multiply is actually not that bad, if bit is set in one operand shift and add the other to an accumulator.  at least a simple multiply (that might be slow).  Look for the hackers delight book or looks like hackersdelight.org might be the same stuff.  Loaded with exactly what you are looking for, how to do this kind of multiply or that kind of divide...

Comment: the original equation only involves floating point addition and multiplication. if i want it to convert to integers and optimize for it (i.e., eliminate floating point operations altogether) then there will be division as well. because .01 will be used as 1/100 as a term in the equal. simplifying several of these terms will yield optimization.

Comment: What kind of hightech humidity sensor do you have that needs 64 bit? There aren't even any A/D converter close to that precision.

Comment: I am sorry that I've failed to clarify this. I'm using Sensirion's humidity sensor. For 12 bit resolution they provided a equation that involved floating point operations. The equation is simple. But if I need to do the whole operation using integers, then perform rounding, that will require 64 bit integer.

Comment: `(15955 * read_out_16bit * read_out_16bit) / 10e10 + 20498 / 10e4` <<< This is something I can't do without 64 bit integer. Current implementation uses double data type. `read_out_16bit` is read out value from the sensor and it is 16 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @Donotalo: No need for 64 bit integers there.  Compute the square, divide by 100000, multiply by 15955, divide by 100, and add 20498.  The result should be an integer in units of .0001.  Not absolutely precise, but probably well within the accuracy of the sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to go into assembly to do this. The obvious things you need are:

- addition
- 2s complement (invert and increment)
- left and right arithmetic shift by 1

From those you can build subtraction, multiplication, long division, and longer shifts. Keep in mind that multiplying two 64-bit numbers gives you a 128-bit number, and long division may need to be able to take a 128-bit dividend.

It will seem painfully slow, but the assumption in such a machine is that you need a small footprint, not speed. I assume you are doing these calculations at the lowest frequency you can.

An open-source library may have a slightly faster way to do it, 
but it could also be even slower.

Comment: about calculation frequency: the calculation has to be done periodically. minimum period is 10 seconds.

Comment: @Donotalo: If the basic clock were 1mhz I would guess a multiplication or division to be on the order of a millisecond, so that should be OK.

Comment: @Donotalo: Of course, a basic IEEE floating-point software library would also be in the same range, and wouldn't be home-grown. Your compiler probably comes with one.

Comment: @Donotalo: Once I stepped through an IEEE floating point addition on an 8088 (16-bit registers). It took around 300 instructions, of which only a few were actually adding. The rest were unpacking, packing, normalizing, checking for special values, etc. But if you don't need it at high frequency, it works just fine.

Comment: we can use two clock speeds: 32K and 500K. 32K is preferred.

Comment: @Donotalo: So maybe 30-60 ms for a basic operation.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a micro-controller you will probably want to use a simple assembly library.  The fewer operations it has to support the simpler and smaller it can be.  You may also find that you can get away with smaller than 64 bit numbers (48 bit, perhaps) and reduce the run time and register requirements.

Comment: Yes since the microcontroller is 8 bits, any multiple of 8 is enough. Some compilers for 8-bit microcontrollers even have an option for 24-bit float. Extending to 64-bit math just slows it down

Answer (score 0):

Whenever speed is a problem with floating point math in small embedded systems, and when integer math is not enough, **fixed point math** is a fast replacement.

http://forum.e-lab.de/topic.php?t=2387

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/other/4024639/Fixed-point-math-in-C

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Floating_Point_Unit